# Creating Installation Package From Pygame

Tags: python-2.7, installation, windows-installer, pygame, pyinstaller

I am making a snake game these days as an assignment...and hope it will be done in 2-3 days...
I wanted to know if there is someway to make a installation type package....like some **setup.exe** so that I need to only install the game on *windows* and then play it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you do not need a "setup.exe"-type installer for PyGame games.

I use cx_freeze (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-freeze/) in Cygwin (http://cygwin.org/) to create binaries for my MS Windows Pygame projects. It is a litte tricky to figure out, but it produces excellent executables.

In most cases it is enough to put the directory produced by cx_freeze into a ZIP file and distribute that.

If you really need an installer, you have to create it *after* you have created the binary.

Try one of these:

- http://www.installjammer.com/ (discontinued)
- http://nsis.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm (commercial)